# Property 'send' does not exist on type 'CallableContext'

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

If i try to do my code with onRequest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61548399/enabling-cors-in-cloud-functions-for-firebase-ionic-angular-firebase-error) is the problem that i get and since someone sugested me to try onCall i get this error

> Property 'send' does not exist on type 'CallableContext'.

This is the code im using

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const docs = express();
docs.use(cors({ origin: true }));


admin.initializeApp()

export const getFeed = functions.https.onCall(async(req, res)=>{
    docs.get = await admin.firestore().collection('posts').limit(10).get()
    res.send(docs.docs.map((doc: { data: any; })=> doc.data))

})
```

Any detailed help please because im new in ionic and angular and firebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onCall functions work very different onRequest functions.  Please [read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) to understand how to write them.

Callable functions **do not** use request and response objects.  They take two arguments, an input data argument, and a context:

```
export const getFeed = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => { ... })
```

To send a response, you should return a promise that resolves with an object to serialize and send back to the client.

```
const querySnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('posts').limit(10).get()
return querySnapshot.docs.map(snap => snap.data())
```

They also handle cors on their own - there is no need to add middleware for that.  In fact, you can not use any express middleware with callable functions.  You will also need to invoke them using the provided client SDK.  They will not work with a regular HTTP request.  The documentation will explain this.

Comment: i really appereciate the answer and got my problem solved, thanks a lot my friend